# Set the correct magento permissions

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions

What are the correct Magento permissions and how can one set them correctly?

Answer (score 1):

no special permissions, you just make sure that files owned by user who runs php or in case of cPanel - cpanel user and group

just update files owner:

```
cd /home/user
chown -R user:user public_html

find public_html -type f -exec chmod -c 640 {} \;
find public_html -type d -exec chmod -c 2750 {} \;

cd /home/user/public_html
find var generated pub/static pub/media -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
find var generated pub/static pub/media -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

instead of changing permissions everytime, login / work as proper user, files owner, from root to php user:

```
cd /home/user/public_html/
su $(stat -c '%U' index.php) -s /bin/bash
whoami
pwd
```

when you add cron, always place it in users crontab, not in root!

```
su $(stat -c '%U' index.php) -s /bin/bash
php bin/magento cron:install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

### Magento 2 recommended folder and file permission

Please follow following terminal commands for folder and file permission.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

find var pub/static pub/media  generated/ app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;

find var pub/static pub/media generated/ app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

For more details refer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: Did you try this solution?