# Possible way to fix luma Layout

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, deploy

[image]
Encounter this issue (Layout are wrong ).What is the possible issue for this?

Tried dicompile, clear cache and reindex.Still not working

exception.log

> main.CRITICAL: Path "/var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/"
>   cannot be used with directory
>   "/var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/"
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException(code: 0): Path
>   \"/var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/\" cannot be used
>   with directory \"/var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/\" at
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/PathValidator.php:61)"}
>   []
>    main.CRITICAL: The specified
>   "/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php.13900"
>   file could not be written
>   Warning!file_put_contents(/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php.13900):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied Class
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested
>   class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory
>   permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento
>   setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory
>   permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate
>   properly, then you must add the generated class object to the
>   signature of the related construct method, only.
>   {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): The specified
>   \"/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php.13900\"
>   file could not be written
>   Warning!file_put_contents(/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php.13900):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied Class
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The
>   requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated'
>   directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the
>   'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated'
>   directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not
>   generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the
>   signature of the related construct method, only. at
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:135)"} []

Comment: you have run deploy command?

Comment: yes command that i have insert : sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: you can check first css and js already available or not ? after given permission of pub var genrated folder 
`sudo chmod -R 0777 pub var generated`

Comment: can you elaborate which css and js i should check?I think i have the proper permission based on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/278519/60921

Answer (score 0):

1.Set Magento 2 recommend permission to folder and files.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/278519/60921

2.Clear regenerated

```
 rm -rf var/cache/ generated/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/
```

3.Run upgrade and static-content commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: tried as according to exact steps ,not working (same result )

Comment: Add your error log

Comment: are you refering system log ?

Comment: exception.log or system.log or apache error.log

Comment: set file permission as root user

Comment: Tried as root and Sudo .Still not working                                                                   I have updated the log ,check above thank in advance

Comment: change into developer mode

Comment: and then run rm -rf var/cache/ generated/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/
$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: i ran  rm -rf var/cache/ generated/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/ $ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f and back to production.Now css and layout is completely missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95170/discussion-between-msa-and-ed-tan).

Answer (score 0):

Run this commands from the Magento Root directory

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: not working,is there any other possibilities that it is from apache2 overwrite?